# Why would rescinding DACA privileges be illegal?

Tags: united-states, immigration

The Supreme Court recently [refused to hear](https://www.cnbc.com/2019/01/22/supreme-court-takes-no-action-on-daca-weakens-trump-hand-in-shutdown-talks.html) a lawsuit regarding the constitutionality of the [DACA policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deferred_Action_for_Childhood_Arrivals). This supposedly prevents Trump from rescinding the DACA program.

But why would cancelling DACA be illegal? If Obama created the program with an executive order, what could possibly prevent Trump from cancelling it with a single stroke of his pen?

Answer (score 1):

Reading the linked article, it appears a district court in California issued an injunction against the administration ending DACA.  According to [this article](https://www.cnn.com/2018/11/08/politics/daca-9th-circuit/index.html), the 9th Circuit Court of Appeals has upheld the injunction, which is why the administration filed an appeal in the Supreme Court, but for now the injunction stands.

The plaintiffs argue the following (quoting their [complaint](http://universityofcalifornia.edu/sites/default/files/UC-DACA-Complaint.pdf)):

> This lawsuit, brought under the Due Process Clause of the Fifth Amendment to the United States Constitution and the Administrative Procedure Act (“APA”), 5 U.S.C. § 706...
>
> Agency action is invalid under the APA if it is “arbitrary, capricious, an abuse of discretion, or otherwise not in accordance with law,” or if it is taken “without observance of procedure required by law.”  5 U.S.C. § 706(2)...  Here, in multiple respects, Defendants failed to “articulate a satisfactory explanation” for their action that would enable a court to conclude that the decision was “the product of reasoned decisionmaking.”  State Farm, 463 U.S. at 52.
>
> Because the Rescission is based on an incorrect legal premise—the purported illegality of DACA—it cannot survive judicial review under the APA.
>
> Finally, in rescinding DACA, Defendants violated the Due Process Clause of the United States Constitution by failing to provide the University with any process before depriving it of the value of the public resources it invested in DACA recipients, and the benefits flowing from DACA recipients’ contributions to the University.  More fundamentally, they failed to provide DACA recipients with any process before depriving them of their work authorizations and DACA status, and the benefits that flow from that status.

I'm trying to find the actual injunction order, but for now this quote from the 9th Circuit Court of Appeals sums up the reason for ordering the injunction (from the [CNN article](https://www.cnn.com/2018/11/08/politics/daca-9th-circuit/index.html)):

> "We conclude that plaintiffs are likely to succeed on their claim that the rescission of DACA -- at least as justified on this record -- is arbitrary, capricious, or otherwise not in accordance with law," reads the opinion from Judge Kim McLane Wardlaw

Comment: But why would the court reject it? Could you summarize their reasoning for a layman?

Comment: Are you asking what arguments the plaintiffs are making that halting the program for those who are already members would be unlawful?  I'm trying to find a summary of their arguments. @JonathanReez

Comment: @JonathanReez: The US Supreme court didn't "reject" the appeal, they chose not to hear it. The Supreme court has the power to choose which appeals they hear. Since they did not hear the case, the ruling of the prior court stands. So their reasoning might be "the prior court was correct", or "there is no constitutional issue in this case that needs deciding, nor conflicting circuit court rulings that need to be resolved", or simply "I don't want to". Only a small percentage of rulings that are appealed to the Supreme Court are heard.

Comment: @sharur I'm talking about the lower courts preventing Trump from shutting down the program

Comment: @JonathanReez: My apologies, I was confused by your usage of the term "reject", when the lower court did not (and can not) reject the appeal; The appeals court upheld the lower court ruling. Here is the text of the appeals court decision: http://cdn.cnn.com/cnn/2018/images/11/08/18-15068.opinion.pdf (Warning, it's long)

Answer (score 0):

Unlike a circuit appeals court, you do **not** have the right to appeal to the Supreme Court. You have to ask and they have to say yes. They do not have to give any reason for saying no.

That said, the Supreme Court usually refuses to hear an appeal because a) on a brief reading the lower court seems to have got it right or b) the matter is not important enough for the court’s time.